# Counting in groups

Tags: excel, excel-tables

Consider the following table in Excel:

```
status   | order | attribute 
---------------------------
purchased| table | brown
purchased| table | yellow
purchased| table |
purchased| sofa  |
purchased| sofa  | green
purchased| sofa  | 
purchased| pillow| brown
purchased| pillow| yellow
purchased| pillow|
shipped  | lamp  |
shipped  | lamp  |
shipped  | lamp  |
shipped  | desk  | brown
shipped  | desk  | 
shipped  | desk  |
```

I am trying to count each `order` by the `attributes`, so I can get a summary of the following data:

1. Number of unique `orders` with no `attributes`
2. Number of unique `orders` where one `order` has the `brown` `attribute` but no other `attributes`
3. Number of unique `orders` where one `order` has the `brown` `attribute` and another has the `yellow` `attribute`

and so on. Ideally these numbers could also be split by `status` as well.

But based on the above table, the summary should look like this:

1. Number of unique `orders` with no `attributes`: 1 (lamp)
2. Number of unique `orders` where one `order` has the `brown` `attribute` but no other `attributes`: 1 (desk)
3. Number of unique `orders` where one `order` has the `brown` `attribute` and another has the `yellow` `attribute`: 2 (table and pillow)

I've been Googling and testing for hours but to no avail.

Comment: You should investigate count() and countifs().

Comment: @SolarMike Count() and Countifs() won't do unique. This can be done with pivot tables and pivot of pivots, or with modern Excel data model and the Distinct aggregation.

Comment: It is possible to do it with Frequencies, but I wouldn't really recommend it unless the other methods aren't available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data to the Excel data model and then build pivot tables with the "distinct count" aggregation. Play with the order of things to arrive at your desired results. You may need to build more than one pivot table to show all your desired outcomes.

[image]